# Access switch (for configuration) remotly using telnet

Tags: switch

i know that if i want to access to switch remotly (for configuration) using TELNET from a network where the switch dosen't belong using ip default-gateway.

but what if i want to access to ths switch remotly from another network (different than the 1st network), does switch accept 2 or more ip default-gateway ?.
thank you.

Comment: The *default gateway* needs to be able to connect anywhere, otherwise it's unsuited as such.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

A default gateway for switch management is just like a default gateway in any other host. The switch management acts like a host on a network. The configured gateway for a host must be on the same network as the host itself. The gateway is a host on the network that knows how to reach other networks, and traffic from a host that is destined to other networks is sent to the gateway configured in the host.

See the answers to [Meaning of the ip default-gateway L2 switch](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/25827/8499) for an explanation of what happens.